# How can I divide my time series dataset into train and test based on a condition?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

Here is my task:

> Split the data into two datasets: a training dataset and a test dataset. The training dataset should incude the first 7,111 observations (until the last observation of 2004). The aim will be to use the training dataset to forecast the value of NOx concentration at 9am in January 2005. Therefore, split the original dataset into a training and a test dataset. The test dataset should include the 31 observations at 9am every day in January 2005

These are the variables in my dataset and their are 9375 observations:

- Date Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
- Time Time (hh:mm:ss)
- NOx True hourly averaged NOx concentration in ppb
- NO2 True hourly averaged NO2 concentration in microg/m3 Temp Temperature in °C
- RH Relative Humidity (% )
- AH Absolute Humidity

I used:

```
airdata_train <- airdata[1:7111,]
airdata_test <- subset(airdata,Date > 31/01/2005 & Date <= 01/01/2005, select = airdata)
```

but I'm unable to figure how to put multiple conditions.